# What is the natural/normal aspect ratio of videos created either by vLine or by WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, vline

Whe creating a video element using vLine's `createVideoElement` function, what is the aspect ratio of the video that will be shown in that element? Is there a default ratio - one that `WebRTC` generates - or is it something that is set programmatically (e.g., inside a library like `vLine`)?

Comment: Does the `createVideoElement` create an HTML5 video tag?  If so, then you cannot change the aspect ratio, that is only determined by the video src itself.  You can set the width/height, but the aspect ratio itself will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks, ChrisO. Yes, the `createVideoElement` does create the tag. But, I'm not looking to *change* the aspect ratio. I just want to know what it is - so that i can in fact set the width and height of the video container to preserve that aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default aspect ratio should be 4:3 when using [`createVideoElement`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaStream#createVideoElement) in the [vLine API](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/).